# Warning message in log files each time I run a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a rake task that outputs this warning message to the log.

".rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/memoizable-0.4.2/lib/memoizable/method_builder.rb:117:in `call': [DEPRECATION] #verified is deprecated. Use #verified? instead."

I don't have the memoizable gem within my project so I'm not sure what might be generating the warning.

My rake task still runs - it's just outputting this message for each record I process.

I'm running Rails 4.1.4 and using Postgres for my database.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you *do* have memoizable in your project, or the gemset you're using.

Comment: Look at your Gemfile.lock to see what is requiring memoizable, then track down where it's calling #verified, then see if there's an update or submit a patch or just live with it :)

Comment: @Dave - you're right.  It's there in the gem set, didn't spot it when I looked first time.

Comment: Ah ha - I think I can see now why I'm getting this warning.  The JSON structure I've working with has a .verified element.  If I comment out that snippet of JSON - no warning message.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation again I realised that the warning was being generated by the Twitter Gem, which has deprecated the user.verify JSON object to a method verified?

I've never understood why the Twitter gem just can't return the straight JSON and leave it to me to manage/process.  But anyhow.  Thanks to those that commented.